# How can i delete charcters from dictionnary [Python]

Tags: python, replace

```
banword = ["/","\n",'"',"'","Badword","*","badword","badword","badword"]
okword = ["","","","","f","","Badword","badword","badword"]
for c in range (1,len(commentaries) + 1):
    azpeo = commentaries[c]
    print(azpeo)
    for c in range(len(banword)):
        azpeo.replace(banword[c],okword[c])
    commentaries[c] = azpeo
```

So here, i am trying to delete bad word from sentences that are contained in a dictionnary, the dictionnary look like that :

````
commentaries = {1 : "sentences", 2 : "sentences"}```
But nothing is changing at all and i can't understand why ?
````

I tried removing characters with `.replace` method by stocking each value in a variable and then using `.replace` but this does not seems to work ?

Comment: Why are you using a dictionary with numeric keys instead of a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`replace` doesnot change your string inplace so you need to assign it to original string.
You need to change

```
azpeo.replace(banword[c],okword[c])
```

To

```
azpeo = azpeo.replace(banword[c],okword[c])
```

Then it will work

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that strings are immutable so you should do at line 7 in your example, the following:

```
azpeo = azpeo.replace(banword[c],okword[c])
```